# Character corruption in the Google Cloud Tools for Eclipse Console

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, console, corruption

When debugging Google App Engine Standard Java Project, I currently use the latest Eclipse and SDK. System.out.println ("中中中"); is executed, Why is that, double-byte character set Chinese characters garbled on the console.

Characters are normally displayed without garbled characters on the console when executing ordinary Java Project, but on the Google App Engine Standard Java Project Console, "������" is displayed and character corruption will appear . I already changed Resource Text file encoding is definitely set to UTF-8.

Does anyone know something about this characters setting in App Engine Eclipse?
Thank you.

Comment: What's the version of your Eclipse? I can't reproduce it on Eclipse Oxygen.

Comment: Check _Window_ > _Preferences_ > _General_ > _Workspace_ > _Text file encoding_. Is it UTF-8? If not, put `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` to your `eclipse.ini`.

Comment: And please report your OS too.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem too.

There's something like

```
�E�� 03, 2018 3:38:32 �W�� com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
```

or

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ??@??��'
```

in my console.

I'm using Eclipse Photon/appengine.api.sdk 1.9.64

Have change 'Text file encoding' to 'UTF-8' and add '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' in eclipse.ini.

This problem occurs on both Win7 and Win10 system.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem by
adding the following to the "WEB-INF/logging.properties":

```
 handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
 java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.encoding=UTF-8
```